# Why the option "Enterprise CA" is greyed out on my Windows Server 2016 VM?

Tags: server, ssl-certificate, certificate, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am running Windows Server 2016 on WMware. When I try to choose the option in the "Specify the setup type of the CA"?[This is the menu on the Windows server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DPHI.png)